# use of "being" in reduced relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

what I have been told is that present participles are used in active reduced relative clauses. considering present participle of "be", which is being, I was wondering can we use the same pattern?
Another example in Longman dictionary is:

1. who heard of a grown man being scared of the dark?
   or
2. who heard of a grown man who is scared of the dark?

Aren't they possibly equivalent of each other?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "a man who is being scared" is not necessarily the same as "a man who is scared", if that's what you're asking. Although "who heard of" can be followed either by a noun phrase or a noun in the objective case and a present participle ("who heard of him playing football?"). It would help if you in the question unpacked a bit more what you think is going on grammatically, what you think it means, and why you think there is or isn't a difference.

Comment: @StuartF ? Huh? Who mentioned "a man who is being scared"?

Comment: The OP discussed reduced relative clauses, which means going from "man who is being scared" to "man being scared". "being scared" could be a reduced relative clause or some kind of verbal noun, but the OP seems to intend the former. Why don't you disappear again?

Comment: The examples are wholly equivalent yet quite separately, neither is realistic. Who doubts that In real English, the phrasing would always be 'who ever heard…'?

Answer (score -1):

The meanings are similar, but they have different emphasis.

> Who has heard of a grown man being scared of the dark?

emphasizes the state of being scared. So it's asking if this condition has ever happened.

> Who has heard of a grown man who is scared of the dark?

emphasizes "grown man". It's asking if anyone knows of a specific man who is scared of the dark.

They're closely related because if you know of such a man, then by implication you know that the condition happened. And if you've heard of the condition, you probably heard who experienced it.

Comment: That seems like a rather esoteric dream trip, the logic having largely nothing to do with the grammar or semantics.

Comment: It is related to the grammar. "X being Y" is a phrase that refers to the "being" relationship between X and Y. "X who/that is Y" is a phrase that refers to X with the Y qualifier.